# Colors in Photoshop CS6/CC look different than in browser?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

One of my friends, a graphic designer told me recently that sometimes colors in Photshop look slightly different than the ones rendered in browser.

I know it is possible when you save a file and then use it on a website due to palettes, but he uses given color in PS, for example `#b81e1e`, then he creates a DOM element and sets its background to `#b81e1e` and the color is rendered differently in browser than in PS (I guess it's not that subtle as he can easily spot it). It's not a regular thing and it doesn't happen always, but he states it happened to him a few times, although he can't really tell me with witch colors.

Is it even possible? Because I have never really heard about anything like this & nothing like this ever happened to me...

Answer (score 25):

This is most likely a color profile issue.

First off, he should be working RGB and not CYMK or another color space. This is easy enough to check, simply go to Image > Mode and ensure it's set to RGB. My guess is it probably is.

The second issue is a color profile. This may be set to something else. It should be using sRGB IEC61966-2.1, which is considered a standard for most PC monitors. The easiest way to check this is to go to Edit > Color Settings. If it's set to the "North America General Purpose 2" or "North America Web/Internet" it should be working fine.

The final step is to setup a "proof setup" that will set a monitor color preview. Go to "View > Proof Setup > Monitor RGB". Then, you can toggle on/off the proof colors by using the shortcut (depends on OS) for Proof Colors, which is under the View toolbar.

I'm not intimately familiar with color profiles in Photoshop, but these are the steps I take if I find color mismatches. Normally it's a non-issue for me.

[more info on color profiles](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/07/30/photoshop-color-profiles-for-web-images/)

Comment: To add to that, I'd also say make sure you're viewing it on the same monitor as well, just to verify as different monitors will display things differently.

Comment: Choosing "Monitor RGB" in View > Proof Setup fixed the problem with wrong colors. I think it was switched by mistake with some keyboard combination.

Comment: @vovahost, this is very common, in fact my first run-in with color problems was that exact issue (accidental hotkey)

Comment: Oh. My. God. 15 years working with Photoshop and I've never used that setting. Somehow it switched to CMYK. It doesn't appear to be relative to the open document, as I just started a new App from a default preset. So either it came from a previous opened document or a hotkey, like you said. Thanks so much, I'll be keeping a closer eye on this setting and use it!

Comment: This completely solved my issue. I've used photoshop for years and didn't know about it either, I just thought that it was because the document was in CMYK. It wasn't until I saw it on another colleagues computer did I realise it was wrong.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to "Proof Setup"! Fixed the issue I was having with PSD colors not matching the HTML/CSS colors.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl I first had this problem when I had accidentally hit a hotkey for Proof Setup as well! Normally color profiles are used for print work (trying to replicate real-world colors as best as it can) -- so it can be frustrating when you accidentally enable it for web work.

Comment: This is happening in PDSs from a specific designer I work with who is sending me files for a web project. What does she need to change on her end in the files?

Answer (score 4):

Aware I'm very late to the party - Had the same issue and after trying the previous answers I still had the problem, hopefully this helps someone else in future -

The fix that worked for me:
File > Save For Web > Uncheck 'Convert to sRGB' > Save

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a long headache.

Answer (score 3):

As an update for Photoshop CC also change:

EDIT> CONVERT TO PROFILE... and set Destination Space Profile to sRGB IEC61966-2.1

That was my particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to color profiles Mattc0m's answer speaks about, the bigger problem is the monitors themselves.

If I simply adjust the brightness and contrast on my monitor, it displays color differently.

I have two mismatched monitors on my setup. They are both plugged into the same hardware and have each been calibrated with the same calibration device and they each have their individual custom calibration profile loaded at startup. They do not display color the same.

When I upload an image to a webserver for the world, I have zero control over the client's browser (which may or may not honor embedded profiles) and the client's monitor. You learn to accept the slack.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because of your browser is not color managed. Try using Firefox and turning on Color Management as descibed here (http://www.gballard.net/photoshop/srgb_wide_gamut.html#) and see if sth will change.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the "export for web" function. That way it will convert the colors to a format that will appear in the browser the same way it did on your photoshop canvas.

Comment: Hi Dominik, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score -3):

When selecting a color, there's a small checkbox at the bottom left that says, "Only Web Colors". Make sure it's checked, and you should be fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further?

Comment: This is a terrible idea; You're limiting yourself to a very small palette of colors (216 to be precise) and this will *only* prevent color differences on devices that only display color in 8-bit (which these days is basically none)

Answer (score -5):

Found this video for a quick FIX. Its roughly a 1 minute video that shows how to fix the color profile issue so images show up properly in Adobe Photoshop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aB_xN2kLVCE

Comment: do not post a link-only answer, please explain what we'll find behind that link. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!